# $\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1+\cos^2(x)}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$ but $\int \frac{dx}{1+\cos^2(x)}=\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt2}\right)$ is zero

Tags: integration

$\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1+\cos^2(x)}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$ but $\int \frac{dx}{1+\cos^2(x)}=\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt2}\right)$ is zero at $x=\pi$ and $x=0$

I didnot understand the problem why wolfram gives nonzero result although I find 0 by definite integral?

Comment: The function $\;\tan x\;$ is defined only between two non-even consecutive multiples of $\;\pi/2\;$ ...

Comment: Understood, well now, how in order to evaluete the result of the definite integral what should I do,  I might split it into two, [0,pi/2],[pi/2,pi] and taking limit at pi/2

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale Yes, that approach exists, as my answer shows.

Answer (score 4):

For the $x$ range $[0,\,\pi/2)$, $\tan x$ is positive and increasing; on $(\pi/2,\,pi]$, $\tan x$ is negative and increasing. That sounds impossible, but it's because of the behaviour each side of $x=\pi/2$ viz. $\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^\pm}=\mp\infty$. Evaluating a definite integral by substitution requires splitting where such behaviours occur:$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\arctan\tfrac{\tan x}{\sqrt{2}}\right]_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\color{blue}{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\arctan\tfrac{\tan x}{\sqrt{2}}\right]_{\pi/2+\epsilon}^\pi=\tfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\implies\int_0^\pi\tfrac{dx}{1+\cos^2x}=\tfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}.$$(Your original statement of the integrand forgot the blue factor, by the way.) A safe way not to encounter this subtlety is to use the integrand's symmetry around $\pi/2$ viz.$$\int_0^\pi\tfrac{dx}{1+\cos^2x}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\tfrac{2dx}{1+\cos^2x}=\left[\sqrt{2}\arctan\tfrac{\tan x}{\sqrt{2}}\right]_0^{\pi/2}=\tfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}.$$